# Letters becoming "&#235;"

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

I Have a website, and there a few textboxes. If the users fill in something that contains the letters "ë" then it becomes like:

```
&#235;
```

How can I store it ë like this in the database? 
My website is built on .NET and Iam using the C# language.

Comment: Your special characters will turn into ascii, it isn't a big deal in most cases unless it is causing you errors.

Answer (score 4):

Both ASP.Net (your server-side application) and SQL Server are Unicode-aware.  They can handle different languages, and different character sets:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx

> Internally, the code behind ASP.NET Web pages handles all string data
>   as Unicode. You can set how the page encodes its response, which sets
>   the CharSet attribute on the Content-Type part of the HTTP header.
>   This enables browsers to determine the encoding without a meta tag or
>   having to deduce the correct encoding from the content. You can also
>   set how the page interprets information that is sent in a request.
>
> Finally, you can set how ASP.NET interprets the content of the page
>   itself — in other words, the encoding of the physical .aspx file on
>   disk. If you set the file encoding, all ASP pages must use that
>   encoding. Notepad.exe can save files that are encoded in the current
>   system ANSI codepage, in UTF-8, or in UTF-16 (also called Unicode).
>   The ASP.NET runtime can distinguish between these three encodings. The
>   encoding of the physical ASP.NET file must match the encoding that is
>   specified in the file in the @ Page encoding attributes.

This article is also helpful:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893663

This "Joel-on-Software" article is an absolute must-read

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely Positively Must Know About Unicode (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Please read all three articles, and let us know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need `HtmlEncode` and `HtmlDecode` functions.

SQL Server is fine with `ë` and any other local or 'unusual' characters but HTML is not. This is because some characters have special meanings in HTML. Best examples are `<` or `>` which are essential to HTML syntax but there is lots more. For some reason `ë` is also special. To be able to display characters like that they need to be encoded before transmission as HTML. Transmission means also sending to a browser.

So, although you see `ë` in a browser your app is handling it in an encoded version which is `&#235;` and it's always in this form including database. If you want `&#235;` to be saved in SQL Server as `ë` you need to decode it first. Remember to encode it back to `&#235;` before displaying on your page.

Use these functions to decode/encode all your texts before saving/displaying respectively. They will only convert special characters and leave alone everything else:

```
string encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Noël")
string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("No&#235;l")
```

There is another important reason to operate on encoded texts - JavaScript injections. It is an attack on your site meant to disrupt it by placing JavaScript chunks into edit/memo boxes with a hope that they will get executed at one point on someone else's browser. If you encode all texts you get from UI, those JavaScripts will never run because they will be treated as texts rather than an executable code.